# Internet connection is slow when in normal mode but works fine in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers, safe-mode

When I use Windows 7 in Safe Mode with Networking, my download speed is 16 MB/s. In normal mode it's about 4 MB/s.

It is not a virus issue. I use Microsoft security essentials.

I think I have deduced it to a driver or application causing the problem but I don't know which one.

Comment: Try turning off firewall and anti-virus, which would normally be disabled in safe mode. If you get your speed back, turn them back on, then look for an alternative FW/AV solution with lower impact.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a better idea of what is your problem by opening Windows Task Manager:

- Right-click the taskbar, and then click **Start Task Manager**.
- Go to the process tab and order by memory usage to see which takes the most CPU & Memory usage.

You can kill some **unessessary process**** and see if it solves the problem. If it does, then you will know which one was in cause and investigate further to finally maybe uninstall it or deactivate it from windows startup.

If it don't work, try comparing which processes are running/not running between Safe Mode and normal mode (take a screen capture of it, it is easier to compare that way :) )

**unessessary *processes includes all processes specific to the user (has your user or others usernames next to the process) running, excluding Windows official processes and SYSTEM Processes necessary for your system to work correctly*

Hope it helps.

Comment: Windows automatically hides all of its processes, its the SYSTEM Processes on the normal Processes window that need to be kept running such as Explorer.exe. the processes specific to the user can all be stopped without harming the computers performance.

Comment: No worries bud I made the mistake when I was younger of stopping the Explorer.exe process thinking it was Internet explorer... never been so scared that I'd killed my computer in my life haha!

Comment: Hahaha, well good for you then :) So I can help you better with your problem, can you give me your PC brand/model? My friend had a similar problem with one of his PCs and I am wondering if it can be the same thing.